# Ubuntu 21.10 - a2dp unavailable

Tags: ubuntu, bluez, pulseaudio

```
$ pacmd set-card-profile 2 a2dp_sink
Failed to set card profile to 'a2dp_sink'
```

Ubuntu 21.10, pulseaudio, Bluetooth headphones

Only HFP is available and A2DP cannot be turned on.

Answer (score 2):

Please follow the instructions below:

```
sudo apt-get remove bluez
sudo apt-get install pulseaudio-module-bluetooth
```

Comment: I’ve tried this and it worked as a temporary solution but the problem reappeared later. As a temporary solution, [just restarting](https://askubuntu.com/a/1228816/250300) might suffice.